# Print ASCII characters in multiple columns in C

Tags: c, printf, ascii, multiple-columns

I'm new to C and I need to print all ASCII characters in columns (going in order per column and not per row) however the user needs to be able to choose, how many columns are displayed.

I'm able to do it with a specific number of columns, but I can't think of way without writing 255 different printing formats. Here's part of printing function:

```
int rows = 255/numberOfColumns;
for (i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
{
    printf("%3d = %s\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t"
           "%3d = %c\t\t\n", i, valorControl, i + 32, i + 32,
           i+(32*2), i+(32*2), i+(32*3), i+(32*3), i+(32*4),
           i+(32*4), i+(32*5), i+(32*5), i+(32*6), i+(32*6),
           i+(32*7), i+(32*7));
```

Comment: Why will you need `rows = 255/numberOfColumns`? Is it in the right declaration? And why is there a need?

Comment: Formally, ASCII has 128 characters, 0..127.  Colloquially, 0..255 is OK, but how are you going to present non-printing characters such as form feed, back space, newline, tab, etc?  What range of numbers of columns will you allow?  1? 10? 16?  32?  What code set are you using?  If you have an 8859-n code set (eg 8859-1, 8859-15, etc) then you can charge ahead.  If you work with a UTF-8 terminal, character codes from 0x80..0xBF are continuation bytes, 0xC2..0xF4 are various start bytes, and the rest (0xC0, 0xC1, 0xF5..0xFF) as simply invalid bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: `, i+(32*7), i+(32*7));` — be careful in your copy'n'paste.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the first `%s` as a type instead of `%c`, you could write -

```
int rows = (256+numberOfColumns-1)/numberOfColumns;
for (j=0; j<rows; j++){
    for (i=0; i<numberOfColumns; i++){
        int character = i*rows+j;
        if(character>=256)
            break;
        printf("%3d = %c\t\t", character, character);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The outer loop is the same as the loop in your code (a bit more accurate). The inner loop prints each column with tabs.

Also, you should try to print only printable characters. Even among the printable characters, the characters like `\t` and `\n` are going to destroy your alignment.

You can do that with -

```
printf("%3d = %c\t\t",character, isprint(character)?character:'_');
```

This only prints the printable characters and prints a `'_'` for the rest.

Here is the [DEMO](https://ideone.com/KFuwM9)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. And yeah i had the `%s` because i was using a variable to represent all the non-printing characters and forgot to change it when I posted the question, my bad!